# Desktop Widget using PHP

Tags: php, windows, desktop, widget

I need to create a desktop widget where the users wants to update their details from
 the desktop html file.i haved tried with ajax but the value getting stored in the database 
but the response cannot get back to html file,i have included the remote js file into the 
html file. Im using Windows OS, php 5, Xampp server.

the sample script is follows,

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://bizzedge.freezyads.com/scripts/widget.js" 

></script>

<input type="text" value="75" style="border:0; width:20px;" maxlength="2" 

onblur="myscore(this.value,'51')" 
/>
```

Comment: I don't understand what the actual problem is and what kind of desktop widget you are creating.

Comment: thanks pekka
actually i wants to provide some html code to user where they was save to their desktop,whenever the user execute the html file and update some values in the textbox provided in the html code,once they entered their value its wants to updated in to our database and we wants to send back the updated value to the user,i have accessed the server(php) file by using ajax and its working fine up to update the value but while i alert the responseText its returning empty but i have echo(ed) lots of values in the php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear you're using using GET query parameters, but sending the AJAX request via POST.

```
var url='http://bizzedge.freezyads.com/ajax/widget.php?id='+id+'&usr='+user;
...
xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Not that it seems to matter, as the script gives me output when I hit the URL directly in Firefox (broken image, mangled layout, but at least it's a response). A proper POST AJAX request done this way would pass the paramters in the `.send()` call:

```
xmlhttp.send('id=' + id + '&usr=' + user);
```

I would suggest using [jQuery](http://jquery.org/) or [MooTools](http://mootools.net/) to handle the AJAX side of things. They provide far more debugging capabilities in case something blows up, rather than trying to roll your own handlers. As well, use something like [HTTPFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647/), which will let you monitor HTTP requests as they come/go from the browser. With this you can see the response in its raw state (and its headers) as it comes back before any processing.